# Adding a Most Recent Saved Time in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to add a cell at the bottom of my spreadsheet that simply says the time it was most recently saved. This would need to automatically update every time Google Sheets automatically saves. Does anyone know if there is a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sheet automatically saves whenever it's edited.  There is an `onEdit()` trigger, so you could run the simple `onEdit()` function to enter the date value in the sheet.

```
function onEdit() {
  var thisSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var theLastRow = thisSheet.getLastRow();
  var newRowRange = thisSheet.getRange(theLastRow+1,1);
  var theDateTime = new Date();
  newRowRange.setValue(theDateTime);
};
```

Comment: Awesome...thanks, Sandy! I will need to assign that time output to a specific cell, and have it overwrite the old update each time, but I can hopefully figure that out. Thanks again!